# R: boxplot for columns with different lengths from tsv file

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm trying to generate different boxplots for columns with different lengths coming from a tsv file.

Input format:

```
exons_1    exons_2    exons_3
0          2          2
1          1          2
2          3          1
0          0          
2          2
1
4
```

Then, my script is:

```
input_file = read.table(input.tsv, header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)

boxplot((input_file), ylab="Signal", xlab="Exon-Sets", las=2, names = c("exons_1", "exons_2", "exonset_3"))
```

The output boxplot that I obtain is limited only to the 2 first lines (the shortest column) ignoring the values after the second row.

If I change the script to `fill = FALSE` I obtain a message error like this:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
line 4 did not have 3 elements
Calls: read.table -> scan
Execution halted
```

Anybody can help me to plot all the values for all the columns on different boxplots?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can reshape the data after reading it in, so that one column holds the recorded values for signals and the other the exon set it belongs to. Then, you could easily plot it.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
read.table(text = "exons_1    exons_2    exons_3
0          2          2
1          1          2
2          3          1
0          0          
2          2
1
4", fill = T, header = T) %>%
  gather(exon_set, signal) %>%
  drop_na() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(exon_set, signal)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]